# Powershell with XAML GUI does not read data until end of script

Tags: xml, visual-studio, powershell

First of all, this is my first ever script with a XML GUI so it may be something very obvious that is missing.
Basically, I'm doing a simple script where you choose a customer (translates to OU) and look for a username based on first name. However, the input window takes whatever it says when I run the script (so nothing) and never refresh after I filled in the form.

To clarify, when I click the button I want it to run through the form and see what has been written

If you guys need the XAML code let me know, the Powershell code looks like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
$xamlFile = "$PSScriptRoot\MainWindow.xaml"

$inputXML = Get-Content $xamlFile -Raw
$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"', '' -replace "x:N", 'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
[XML]$XAML = $inputXML
$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
try 
{
    $window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
}
catch 
{
    Write-Warning $_.Exception
    throw
}
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object 
{
    try 
    {
        Set-Variable -Name "var_$($_.Name)" -Value $window.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch 
    {
        throw
    }
}
Get-Variable var_*

$customer = $var_CustomerDropDown.Text
$firstName = $var_FirstnameBox.Text

$var_CreateButton.Add_Click
({
    $var_LogText1.Text = ""
    if ($customer -match "Customer1") 
    {
        $result = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like $firstName' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        foreach ($item in $result)
        {
            $var_LogText1.Text = $var_LogText1.Text + "$item`n" + "Customer1`n"
        }
    }
    if ($customer -match "Customer2") 
    {
        $result = Get-ADUser -Filter 'Name -like $firstName' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
        foreach ($item in $result)
        {
            $var_LogText1.Text = $var_LogText1.Text + "$item`n" + "Customer2`n"
        }
    }     
    else 
    {
        $var_LogText1.Text = "No customer chosen"
    }            
})

$Null = $window.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the form or the xaml it is quite hard to understand what it is exactly you want.

First thing I noticed is that your filter for `Get-ADUser` won't work.
The reason is that the filter string should be enclosed in double-quotes `"`, not single-qoutes `'` otherwise the variable `$firstname` will not get expanded and is taken literally.

Also, if you use the `-like` operator, you should also use wildchar characters. Without it, `-like` works the same as `-eq`.

Use `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$firstName*'"`

Then, the loop to fill the textbox is not needed. You can do that with `$var_LogText1.Text = $result -join [environment]::NewLine`
In fact, this can be written in just one line of code, skipping variable `$result` alltogether. (see below)

The various `if ($customer -match "Customer1") {..}` you have can also be simplyfied. Since you are already using the regex `-match` operator, you can combine the options with the regex **OR** character `|`

```
$var_LogText1.Text = ""
# example match 'Customer1', 'Customer2' or 'John0' to 'John9'
if ($customer -match 'Customer[12]|John\d') {
    # try and get the full usernames and write them each on a separate line in the textbox
    $var_LogText1.Text = (Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '$firstName*'").Name -join [environment]::NewLine
}
else {
    $var_LogText1.Text = "No customer chosen"
}         
# if you need this, you can write these values to the console window too ("see what has been written")
Write-Host $var_LogText1.Text
```